# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for '<data>' with arguments <args> not found. 1 pattern(s) tried

Tags: python, django

Extremely new Django learner here. I am working on a personal project and got this error.
**views.py**

```
def download_video(request):
    ...
    return redirect(reverse('download_status', args=[True, None, str(name)]))

def download_status(request, download_success, download_error=None, video_id=None):
    ...
    context = {
        'download_success': download_success,
        'download_error': download_error,
        'new_filename': video_id,
        'entries_page': paginated_subs,
        'video_id': video_id
    }
    return render(request, 'download_status.html', context)
```

Basically, it is a request from download_video method to redirect to another page that will display the subs list in a paginated manner.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('download/', views.download_video, name='download_video'),
    path('data/<video_id>/', views.download_status, name='download_status'),
]
```

**download_status.html**

```
{% load static %}
<!-- displayer.html -->
...
pagination support code
...
```

I have tried the pagination code and it works, but for the current organization of code, it is giving me this error:

```
ERROR:django.request:Internal Server Error: /video_downloader/download/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\leofi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\leofi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Academics\video_downloader\views.py", line 105, in download_video
    return redirect(reverse('download_status', args=[True, None, str(name)]))
  File "C:\Users\leofi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 88, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\leofi\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 828, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'download_status' with arguments '(True, None, '480OGItLZNo')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['video_downloader/data/(?P<video_id>[^/]+)/\\Z']
```

I have tried looking at the docs and other similar stackoverflow answers but I wasn't able to figure out the problem. I tried casting the `name` to different data types or adding `str:` keyword before `video_id` in the url file but to no avail. How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your path has *one* parameter, `<video_id>`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # …
    path('data/<video_id>/', views.download_status, name='download_status'),
]
```

so you pass one parameter when you calculate the reverse: the value for the `video_id`, so:

```
def download_video(request):
    # …
    return redirect(reverse('download_status', args=[str(name)]))
```

where `str(name)` thus should be the item for the `video_id`. Beware that it can not contain slashes.

you can by the way simplify this and let [**`.redirect(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) handle reversing the url:

```
def download_video(request):
    # …
    return redirect('download_status', str(name))
```

you can also make it more verbose by specifying the name of the URL parameter:

```
def download_video(request):
    # …
    return redirect('download_status', video_id=str(name))
```

Comment: Ohhh, so does that mean if I want to build a context object based on the values in my download_video method, I can't just pass the values on the download_status method? And I can only pass the parameters mentioned in the URL? Interesting!

Comment: @Leofierus: yes, what happens is that it constructs a path. Next when that browser visits the path, it will "parse" the URL patterns into parameters for the view, but you thus can not "hide" data in the redirect. it is all in the path.